# Can the grouping factor of a mixed effect model include missing values?

Tags: mixed-model, missing-data, random-effects-model

This may be a stupid question but: **can a mixed effect model include a *random effect factor* (grouping factor) that has some missing values?** I guess it would bias the variance estimates but could the model still be "useful"? Alternatively, what would be the proper way to handle such a case (e.g. delete rows with missing information? Consider these missing factor levels as "single groups"?)?
In my case, I can manage without the grouping factor but I think the question is theoretically interesting anyway and I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean that you know that a case belongs to one of the groups in your grouping factor, but you don't know which particular group? Or do you mean that a case might belong to a group beyond those included in your grouping factor?

Comment: Well, both! I hope it's relevant but my missing values are (I think) missing at random. The grouping factor is the *ring ID* of adult birds (parents) that we assigned to nestlings (children). While chicks cannot escape us, adults can or may be absent during our visits so we don't always know the identity of the parents. Yet, parents may have several broods so many chicks may share the same parental ID. Chicks can also have parents that never had other broods, but we may know them or not. Knowing parents matters as they influence children! This is but one examples, many others surely exist.

Comment: For missing at random data, Stef van Buuren's [FIMD](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-missmult.html) in Section 7.3 provides some references for multiple imputation of missing "class membership," which is equivalent to the _ring ID_ if you know all possible adults and their _ring ID_ values. I don't know whether there's any good way to handle completely unknown/unlabeled parents with that type of approach. My sense is that this might be handled nicely by a Bayesian model, but that's beyond my expertise.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful link, I'll look into that.